# How to not add a carriage return (char(13)) if a value is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to figure out a way to create a column where it has address lines in the same column but after each address line there is carriage return. e.g.

```
123 fake street [carriage return]
Fake City [carriage return]
Fake County [carriage reutrn]
```

Now I do not want to add a carriage return if the fake city is null other wise you get

```
123 fake street [carriage return]
[carriage return]
Fake County [carriage reutrn]
```

This is what I have as my query:

```
o.ADD_1 + CHAR(13) + o.ADD_2 + CHAR(13) + o.ADD_3 + CHAR(13) + o.ADD_4 + CHAR(13) + 
o.POST_CODE AS FULL_OWNER_ADDRESS_LIST
```

I have tried this

`ISNULL(o.ADD_2 + CHAR(13) , '')`

But obviously it will never be null because of the char(13).

To keep it simple here is the table in use called OWNERS

```
Add_1 | Add_2 | Add_3 | Add_4 | Postcode
```

Using SQL Server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your table structure.  If you have not decided yet, please post your most likely candidates.

Comment: Structure is huge. But you should probably be able to figure it out with the fields I have?

Comment: Please define your fields that you show the data for. Do you store each address line separately or the entire address as some form of text field (TLOB or something)?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You can use [CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which ignores NULL values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But obviously it will never be null because of the char(13).

Not unless you have set [the `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql) to `OFF`, which is non-standard and slated to be removed in "a future version" of SQL Server.

With that option set `ON`, which is the default and standards-compliant setting, `Null + CHAR(13)` will still be `Null`.

Comment: Okay, yes, you're right. The value is not returning null, it is returning an empty string!

Comment: This is where NULLIF comes in handy